# How do you add an instance to an instanced object using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a simple chrome extension and I want to instance Trello-like list. That turned out successful as I easily found a way to instance it. However, I want to create a delete button and when I instance them, they only stay on the first instanced object. I considered using lists or variables to change the id each time but I think it's going to make things more complicated. How can I fix this?

code:

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Esse</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <script type="text/javascript"                     src="popup.js"></script> 
        <h1 class="logo">Esse</h1>
        <p class="by">by</p> 
        <p class = "Minim">Minim</p>
     <!--   <img src="images/logo_transparent.png"   width="60" height="60" class="studiologo"> -->
        <div class="container" id="container">
            <ul class="hwcontainer" id="Lcontainer">
                <li><input type="button" id="button"    value="+" class="addlist" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var listnum = 0;
var butadd = 250;
var numadd = 360; 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' ,addList, false);

function addList()
{
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        var new_list = document.createElement('DIV');
        new_list.innerHTML = "CLICK";
        new_list.className = "list";
        new_list.id = 'newList';

        var delete_list =   document.createElement('BUTTON');
        delete_list.className = "delList";
        listnum++;
        extendCont()
        document.getElementById('Lcontainer').appendChild(new_list            );
        document.getElementById('newList').appendChild(delete_list);
}, false);
}

function extendCont(){
    if (listnum >= 5)
    {
    document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", 'height: '+numadd+'px');
    document.getElementById('button').setAttribute("style", "top:"+ butadd + 'px');
    numadd += 60;
    butadd += 60;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element IDs need to be unique in the whole document.

All your lists get the same ID "newList".

When you try to add the button `document.getElementById('newList')` will always return the first list.

You can fix this by assigning unique element ids. You can use a counter (like you already have) for this:

```
new_list.id = 'newList' + listnum;
```